# Can't change Theme or Icons in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, icons, xfce, appearance

As said by another user in a similar post, I can't change the set of fonts, icons etc. in Settings/Appearance. I can reach the menu, but the window then freezes for a bit and shuts down after a few seconds. Trying to reach the same window via terminal with "xfce4-appeareance-settings" doesn't solve the issue.
Via terminal, I get this error message:

> (xfce4-appearance-settings:4909): GLib-ERROR **:
>   /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.40.2/./glib/gmem.c:133: failed to allocate
>   4136 bytes Rilevato trace/breakpoint (core dump creato)

If it can be of any help, I'm using an Asus EEE Pc 1015-CX.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried here already, you can change settings in the Settings Editor, `xfce4-settings-editor`. Appearance settings are under the section *xsettings*.

**Themes**
You can see your themes by pasting the following in terminal:

```
ls /usr/share/themes/
```

To change a theme you can run something like the following. Just put in the name you like. If it is two words wrap it in quotes.

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName -s Greybird
```

**Icons**
To view icons:

```
ls /usr/share/icons/
```

To change icons:

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/IconThemeName -s Tango
```

**Fonts**
To view fonts (sorry I don't have a better option here):

```
fc-list
```

To set fonts:

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/FontName -s "DejaVu Sans 10"
```

I wish I knew how to fix the actual issue, but I hope this will help a little.

Comment: Good to know! Commands like this one could be further helpful in the future. Anyway, I just solved the issue by entering Synaptic and deleting a few icon packs that were causing issues, notably Moka. Now it works like a charm. But thanks a lot, mate!

Comment: Nice! I'm glad you got the issue resolved. :)